# Default Relayhost and custom relayhost for domains

Tags: email, postfix, smtp

I have a customer which needs a custom relayhost for sending emails. So I want to choose this relayhost only for this domain.

- customer.example.com -> relayhost A
- (all other domains) -> relayhost B

How can I realize this setup in postfix?

Annotation: For the customer incoming email I already installed a transport, which redirects incoming emails to his email Server.

```
Mail to Customer -> MX Entry to Spam Firewall -> My Server -> Customer
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use [transport_maps](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#transport_maps) in [main.cf](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html) to specify optional [transport map](http://www.postfix.org/transport.5.html) for per recipient relay and transport.